# Xcode problem - add view to parent

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm new to Xcode and Objective C coding, and I already have a little problem. 
So I have a mainview with a button. When I press the button a table is showing. (the table is another tableViewController) 
When I press an item on the table, There should be shown another view (on my main window).
I know when you try to add a subview you use it like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:thisistheController.view];
```

But when I use the table, the new view is shown in the table and not on my mainview but on my table. 
like this:

[image]

When I try this:

```
[MainviewController.view addSubview:thisistheController.view];
```

i don't get any errors, or warnings. but the view isn't shown on my main window. 
I also tried to use:

```
[self.parentController.view addSubview:thisistheController.view];
```

But here I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try...

```
[self.view.superview addSubview:thisisthecontroller.view]
```